# How to create a magento tab with iFrame in admin backend

Tags: magento, iframe, tabs, admin

I have magento 1.5.1.0 and I want to add an extra menu or tab on the admin (backend) area of magento.

The content of the menu will be just an iFrame for loading an external page. The reason for this is that I want the user to have access to magento and the webpage of a CRM from the same view (without leaving from magento admin).

Can i implement this feature to magento?

Comment: Here is the link that you can take referense. [Add Custom Tabs to the Magento Product Admin](http://fishpig.co.uk/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i don't want a tab to the product view-edit.
I want a new menu or tab to the admin menu.
a menu like the CMS - Reports - System etc..

Comment: don't forget to clear cache!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem here http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/coffeefreak-blank-magento-extension-for-building-main-admin-menu-with-sidebar-and-tabs/
Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample. Our module is "ARTLantis_SAP", the directory structure :

```
ARTLantis
  |_SAP
      |_etc
      |  |_ adminhtml.xml
      |  |_ config.xml
      |_Helper
         |_ Data.php
```

**adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<config>
<menu>
    <sap>
        <title>SAP</title>
        <sort_order>15</sort_order>
        <children>
            <sapmenu>
                <title>SAP FA Screen</title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/sap/index</action>
            </sapmenu>
        </children>
    </awesome>
</menu>
```

This will create a "SAP" menu in admin section which you over the mouse, it will show "SAP FA Screen" child menu item. But, when you click the child menu item, it will throw an error because still isn't available controller yet.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<config>
<modules>
    <ARTLantis_SAP>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </ARTLantis_SAP>
</modules>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <sap>
                <file>sap.xml</file>
            </sap>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <sap>
                        <title>SAP Menu</title>
                        <children>
                            <sapmenu>
                                <title>SAP Menu Item</title>
                            </sapmenu>
                        </children>
                    </sap>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <sap>
            <class>ARTLantis_SAP_Helper</class>
        </sap>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

**Data.php**

```
<?php 
   class ARTLantis_SAP_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
   {
   }
?>
```

Comment: I suppose the above code will add the menu. But what code should i use to embed the iFrame..?